# Strange UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, celery

Here is my simple code:

```
r = (detection and detection['objects'] and detection['objects'][0]['r'] == 1)
if r == True:
    # ...
```

And here is the exception I get:

> File "/***/tasks.py", line 32, in ***
>      if r == True:
>   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment

This code is executed through Celery beat.
I have totally no idea why this error occurs. Someone would have an idea?

Comment: r = (detection and detection['objects'] and detection['objects'][0]['`r`'] == 1) where is this `r` coming from

Comment: The code you've shown won't raise that exception.  So you must be running different code than that.  Show your real code.

Comment: Trust me, it raises this exception. I'm not new in python development, and I made sure this is this code that is actually running.

Comment: What is the value for detection? I thought detection might be undefined or None, but I couldn't reproduce. I also can't get formatting in this comment, so see Python log at http://pastebin.com/ScsCKrvB